# Perixx Perimice-718 wireless mouse lagging on Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, wireless-mouse, mouse-cursor

I've tried using Perixx wireless mouse Perimice-718 under Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel `5.15.0-86`, Xorg `21.1.4-2`) but the mouse keeps lagging behind even with fluent movement over single screen. I'm moving the mouse and cursor moves as well, but in the middle it just stops for a few milliseconds and after while it continues to move. Which is very annoying and makes the mouse unusable under Linux.

The mouse is detected as `MOSART Semi.`

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

with pretty much default properties:

```
$ xinput list-props 11
Device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse':
        Device Enabled (156):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (158): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (291):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (292):       0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (293):        0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (294):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (295):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Button Scrolling Button (296): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (297): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (298):    0
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (299):    0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (300):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (301):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (302):     0.400000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (303):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (304):        1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (305):   1, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (306):   1, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (307):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (308):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (276):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (277):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (278):        0, 0
        Device Node (279):      "/dev/input/event3"
        Device Product ID (280):        1578, 16642
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (309):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (310):       1
        libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (311):        15
        libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (312):        15
        libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (313):    1
```

I've tried changing acceleration profile in KDE config, but without any effect.

USB device:

```
$ lsusb | grep Mos
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:4102 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
```

```
$ grep -B3 -A6 "062a.*4102" /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=062a ProdID=4102 Rev= 3.21
S:  Manufacturer=MOSART Semi.
S:  Product=2.4G Wireless Mouse
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   7 Ivl=4ms
```

Under Windows the mouse seems to be working just fine (battery is ok, the USB dongle is close). Any idea how to improve response times of the device under Linux?

The `mousepoll` interval is set to `0` (default) and the mouse seems to use `Ivl=4ms`.

```
$ systool -m usbhid -A mousepoll
Module = "usbhid"

    mousepoll           = "0"
```